# Facebook Login button just loads when i try to login to my app

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-login

When i click on the facebook login button it shows loading and gets back to the same page.

This is how i initialized Sdk

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    facebookSDKInitialize();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    getLoginDetails(loginButton);
}
/*
 Initialize the facebook sdk
 And then callback manager will handle the login responses.
*/
protected void facebookSDKInitialize() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}
```

I would appreciate quick help regarding this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any fb app in testing device?

Comment: Yes i have facebook app on ma device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable or uninstall your facebook app then it will be fine.The reason is that it will be logged in with facebook app.

Comment: I did that in the manifest and i did login to the app once and after that i have this exception.

Comment: then the probelm is with your facebook app.so you should first disable or uninstall facebook app @Syed Sami